# Git push - remote: fatal: not a git repository: '.'

Tags: git, push

I am currently running into an issue, when trying to push my changes to origin I am getting this error:

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 4.84 KiB | 2.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: fatal: not a git repository: '.'
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ///DIRECTORY
 ! [remote rejected]     TEST -> TEST (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '///DIRECTORY'
```

Pull is working perfektly fine. I only get this error, when I try to push my commits, while working from home. In the office, connected via LAN everything works. I tried it with a mobile hotspot but still no luck.

I tried

```
git init
```

also

```
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

i also tried to add the remote under another name with

```
git remote add --mirror=push NEW //DIRECTORY
```

git remote -v showed the path correctly.
I also have read and write permission for the remote, i checked it several times.

Comment: What OS are you using? Some get fussy about `//` prefixes, especially over unsecured networks.

Comment: @torek i am using Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit. The Repo is on a Network Drive. But I also tried it with the Drive letter, and it still did not work.

Comment: Interesting, but not really something I can help with at this point. You might try using the network protocol variants of `git push`, if that's an option (e.g., if you can ssh to a machine that's on the internal network). The real clue here is the error: `remote: fatal: not a git repository: '.'` which means the spawned other `git` process, which tries to `chdir` to the target location `//DIRECTORY`, winds up with its current working directory not correctly set; if you know a lot about the Windows 10 Enterprise internals, perhaps there's something you can make of this.